# How to shortern a predicate that prints depending on a condition

Tags: prolog

So I have something like this:

```
main :-
% Check whether B,C,D is equal to A
... ,

% Relevant code:

    (
         (B==A -> write('B is the same as A.'));
         (C==A -> write('C is the same as A.'));
         (D==A -> write('D is the same as A.'));

    ).
```

Is there any way that this could be shortened but still print the relevant letter? There could be 100's of letters to test so this current method is not very nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick note in case you weren't aware of this difference: When you call `A == B`, you're resting whether the value bound to the variable `A` is [equivalent](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=compare) to the value bound to variable `B`. But when you use `write/1` to output 
`'B is the same as A.'`, you are just outputting the atomic literal represented by that string of letters. There is no relationship between the character `'A'` as part of an atom and the value bound to a variable which is represented by `A` (no `'`) in your source code.

So I'm not 100% clear on your intended result, but here are two different solutions that demonstrate the use of the [format](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=format-predicates) family of predicates for outputting values and literals:

If you just want to compare the values of two variables, you can use a predicate to perform the comparison and printout the desired result, which can then be used on all members of a list ([`forall/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=forall/2) is appropriate here because we are only concerned with output):

```
report_on_equality(A, B) :-
    A ==  B, 
    format('~w is the same as ~w.~n', [A, B]).
report_on_equality(A, B) :-
    A \== B, 
    format('~w is not the same as ~w.~n', [A, B]).

example_1 :-
    Vals = [1,4,6,1,7],
    forall( member(V, Vals),
            report_on_equality(V, 1)
          ).
```

But there is no reason to output the value of the variables twice in this case, since if they are equivalent, they will of course be the same value. So maybe you actually want to print out uppercase characters that have been previously associated with values. This, of course, requires that you have first made some paring between uppercase characters and some other values. I have chosen to use a simple list of [pairs](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs) for this purpose:

```
report_on_labeled_equality(LabelA-ValA, LabelB-ValB) :-
    ValA == ValB,
    format('~w is the same as ~w.~n', [LabelA, LabelB]).
report_on_labeled_equality(LabelA-ValA, LabelB-ValB) :-
    ValA \== ValB,
    format('~w is not the same as ~w.~n', [LabelA, LabelB]).

example_2 :-
    Vals = ['B'-1, 'C'-3, 'D'-1, 'E'-4],
    forall( member(V, Vals),
            report_on_labeled_equality(V, 'A'-1)
          ).
```